# Aggregating a large dataset in es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have 5 years worth of daily data that I would like to aggregate to the last day of each month with JavaScript/ES6 but I cannot see how I would go about doing this.

Does anyone have a theory or a way of doing this? I haven’t done this much heavy data manipulation in the past so I am not even sure how to approach this, let alone the best approach.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

What I would like to achieve (getting the last day of each month):

```
[
  {
    x: ‘2018-03-31’,
    y: 27
  },
  {
    x: ‘2018-02-28,
    y: 32
  },
  {
    x: ‘2018-01-30,
    y: 27
  },
  {
    x: ‘2017-12-31’,
    y: 27
  },
  {
    x: ‘2017-11-30,
    y: 32
  },
  {
    x: ‘2017-10-31,
    y: 27
  }
]
```

The current data format:

```
[
  {
    x: ‘2018-03-31’,
    y: 27
  },
  {
    x: ‘2018-03-30',
    y: 32
  }
  {
    x: ‘2018-03-29’,
    y: 27
  },
  {
    x: ‘2018-03-28',
    y: 32
  }
]
```

Continuing daily for five years.

Comment: The data, as written isn't valid.

Comment: i would suggest you  give a input and expected output

Comment: @EvanTrimboli, updated with intended output. It's a massive data file so I can't add the full data set.

Comment: @xianshenglu is this better.

Answer (score 0):

try this,`filter` the `input` if the next date of `x` is 1

```js
const input = [
  {
    x: "2018-03-31",
    y: 27
  },
  {
    x: "2018-03-30",
    y: 32
  },
  {
    x: "2018-03-01",
    y: 27
  },
  {
    x: "2018-02-28",
    y: 32
  },
  {
    x: "2018-02-27",
    y: 27
  },
  {
    x: "2018-02-01",
    y: 32
  },
  {
    x: "2018-01-31",
    y: 27
  },
  {
    x: "2018-01-30",
    y: 27
  }
];
let output = input.filter(
  date =>
    new Date(
      new Date(date.x.split("-").join(",")).getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    ).getDate() === 1
);
console.log(output);
```